# If I Shape-Shift, is my movement reset?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement

If I'm a Halfling (with 25ft move speed) and I shapeshift (or polimorph, or something else) into a Raven (with 50ft fly move speed), **what happens to my expended movement**?

Does expended movement reset? E.g., could I move 25feet, shapeshift, and fly an additional 50ft?

Or is it additive? E.g, if I move 25ft, will I only have 25ft movement left?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No. Whatever you moved prior to the shapeshift will be counted against your new movement speed based on PHB 190

> Your movement can include jumping, climbing, and swimming. These
>   different modes of movement can be combined with walking, or they can
>   constitute your entire move. However you’re moving, you deduct the
>   distance of each part of your move from your speed until it is used up
>   or until you are done moving.

And

> **Using Different Speeds** If you have more than one speed, such as your
>   walking speed and a flying speed, you can switch back and forth
>   between your speeds during your move. ***Whenever you switch, subtract
>   the distance you've already moved from the new speed***. The result
>   determines how much farther you can move. If the result is 0 or less,
>   you can’t use the new speed during the current move. For example, if
>   you have a speed of 30 and a flying speed of 60 because a wizard cast
>   the fly spell on you, you could fly 20 feet, then walk 10 feet, and
>   then leap into the air to fly 30 feet more.

So your Halfling moves 25ft then Shapeshifts to a Giant Eagle the 25ft is subtracted from the 80ft Fly speed so you can move only an additional 55 more feet(assuming you fly).

Comment: interesting. so you can walk for 25 feet as a human which normally takes about 6 seconds - action, turn into a fast thing with 60 feet speed and go for another 35 feet which is like 3 more seconds - possible action.

Comment: @OganM 5e rules priorize simplicity over verisimilitude. Furthermore, if "*on your turn, you can move a distance up to your speed* (PBH, p. 190)", the movement doesn't necessarily take the entire 6 seconds of the turn, as you also can take an action, a bonus action and interact with your environment during that turn.